# How to execute stored procedure which insert/update records using VBA?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I created many spreadsheets which use stored procedures. I have a custom VBA code which works fine when I try to get data from SQL. However, today I wanted to execute parametrized stored procedure which inserts and updates data on a database table. When I run macro no errors show up, however there's no insert/update action on database. I have no idea why. I established SQL connection in my workbook (`myConn`) as I do everytime I need to connect with SQL so it's correct for sure. This is my standard VBA code:

```
Sub SaveData()

    Dim myValue As Double   
    myValue = Sheets("XYZ").Range("valueToSave").Value

    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("myConn").OLEDBConnection
        .CommandText = Array( _
         "EXEC DB.[dbo].[myProc] '" & myValue & "'")
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("myConn").Refresh
  
End Sub
```

I need to insert data into column of `decimal(6,4)` type (in SQL table). `myProc` does it perfectly when I run it manually via SSMS but not here using VBA code. `valueToSave` is an Excel range which stores one decimal value (for example: `23,56`, `11,21` etc.). When I run macro nothing happens. When I run macro and go to 'Connection Properties' > 'Definitions' > 'Command Text' then I can see there's a procedure with parameter (EXEC DB.[dbo].[myProc] '11,23'). So my acode above seems working but not executing stored procedure.

[image]

Has it something to do with data type? Honestly, I tried with other VBA types: `String`, `Variant`, `Integer` but it's not working. I also changed data type of that column in SQL table (to `varchar`, `int` etc.) but it also doesn't work. The most interesting thing is that the code above works fine when I withdraw data from db, it doesn't work when need to insert/update data.

PS. I guess I added all required refrences:

[image]

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is dangerous; it is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Fix your code, and ***parametrise***.

Comment: I use parameters in stored procedure. Anyways, code is used internally, in my company. I just wanted to know why insert/update is not working here

Comment: `"EXEC DB.[dbo].[myProc] '" & myValue & "'"` is **not** using parameters... That is **injection**...

Comment: *"Anyways, code is used internally, in my company"* That's like saying "I only park my car outside my residence and Office, so it's safe to leave it unlocked."

Comment: The stored procedure may have parameters, but the SQL code you are submitting does not. Consider Alice entering something like the following into your Excel cell: `'; drop database DB; --`. Time to read up on [OleDbCommand Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters) and translate that code to VBA.

Comment: When you run in SSMS do you write literally EXEC DB.[dbo].[myProc] '11,56'? or is it with point instead of comma? Or maybe without quotes? You should paste myProc code (at least the signature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ADODB

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveData()

    Const PROC_NAME = "DB.dbo.myproc"

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ado As ADODB.Connection, cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim sCon As String, v As Single

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    v = wb.Sheets("XYZ").Range("valueToSave").Value
    
    ' get connection string
    sCon = wb.Connections("myConn").OLEDBConnection.Connection
    sCon = Replace(sCon, "OLEDB;", "")

    ' open connection
    Set ado = New ADODB.Connection
    ado.Open sCon

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = ado
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = PROC_NAME
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P1", adDecimal, adParamInput)
        With .Parameters(0)
            .NumericScale = 2
            .Precision = 18
            .Value = v
        End With
        .Execute
    End With
    ado.Close

    MsgBox PROC_NAME & " " & v, vbInformation, "Done"

End Sub
```